# What is a good lightweight ORM for my need using Kotlin?

Tags: database, kotlin, orm, aws-lambda, serverless

**Scenario :**

I am having an application where I am using AWS Lambdas which are written in Kotlin to query data from a relational DB residing in AWS.

--

My problem is that I want to use an ORM for firing these queries. I dont want to use hibernate as it is too heavy and takes too long to setup, and I need a solution that would take up the least time in setting up and firing from the Lambdas. I have looked upon multiple ORMSs like Exposed, Requery, Jooq, Ktorm and Squash.

Is anybody out there having experience with any of these libraries in the serverless context? What are your experiences with them and what would you suggest using in my scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at exposed, https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Squash with the Hikari connection pool for some large projects and I have been very happy with it. I like that is is very extensible and my team has been able to solve any issues that come up, implementing extensions to the dialect and the simplicity of defining TableDefinition classes makes it work well for generating code. It is also very self contained with very few dependencies and light on reflection, so should be good for serverless though I have not personally used it for that.

Squash is less an ORM than an sql abstraction / translation layer that ties into entities and it doesn't try to solve all the problems that something like hibernate does. In my experience ORMs start as simple, efficient, and powerful projects and grow to heavyweight libraries that try to do too much and their complexity begins to cause issues when the developer cannot easily see what's going on in the chain from usage through to the database / storage mechanism.

One negative about squash that deserves mention is that, while it is a jetlbrains official library and created by a kotlin developer, support is limited as orangy, the creator, is quite busy and I have feature pull requests outstanding, with many more of them backed up currently. I chose it because I favored it's simplicity and extensibility among a small but advanced team of developers all capable of improving upon it.

Which ever library you choose I hope these factors assist you in making your decision at the least.

Comment: I'm also looking for something super lightweight on top of SQL using Kotlin. What are your thoughts on Squash vs Ktorm? https://www.ktorm.org/ Or even JOOQ? https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/jooq-and-kotlin/

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. We are still using squash with generated code and we are leveling it up more and more with KSP based generators. We have it on our list to share our work for others. jOOQ is great, but the customization of its generated output was quite hard and dense to work with, which is why we ultimately moved on. The creator of jOOQ has made the library thorough and very well documented. I really like their mentality and feature coverage. I haven't checked out ktorm yet, but it looks to have taken a very similar direction to squash which I like.